# Jquery - Automatically add current year months to dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to automatically add the current months of the year, for the current year to a Bootstrap dropdown list.

Currently, I am adding them manually as I am not very good at JavaScript.

How can I automatically add the current months left in the year to the list?

Now we are in February it wouldn't add January cause its already passed.

I have made a bootply so you can see what I mean.

http://www.bootply.com/N2H0BAoapL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can get the month from the current date using `getMonth()`. From there you can loop through the remaining months and populate a `select`, something like this:

```js
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var month = (new Date()).getMonth();
for (; month < monthNames.length; month++) {
  $('select').append('<option>' + monthNames[month] + '</option>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

This basic logic can in turn be reduced to this:

```js
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var html = monthNames.slice((new Date()).getMonth()).map(function(month) {
   return '<option>' + month + '</option>';
}).join('');
$('select').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory thats exactly what i was looking for, thank you

Comment: @Rory what is `for (;` mean? (ignore first param). i just know it

Comment: @user1673498 no problem, glad to help

Comment: @plonknimbuzz that's right - it basically means that I don't need to define an iterating variable in the `for` as I can use the `month` which I already defined.

Answer (score 4):

Below is my example which helped to me display ***ONLY VALID Months for the current year or All Months for Previous Years*** in a Cascading Dropdown of Month.

[image: Snapshot of Current Year Versus Previous Year]

This Example below will disable Cascaded Month Drop if Invalid Year is Selected and will also take care of current valid months as per the choice of the year.

```js
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
var cascadedDropDownMonthId = "#dropDownYearMonth";

//Adding Last 10 Years to Year Drop Down
for (var i = currentYear;i > currentYear - 10 ; i--)
{
$("#dropDownYear1").append('<option value="'+ i.toString() +'">' +i.toString() +'</option>');
}
 
//Disabling Month Dropdown in case of invalid Selections.
$(cascadedDropDownMonthId).prop("disabled", true);

$("#dropDownYear1").change(function () {

            var currentSelectedValue = $(this).val();
            
            if (currentSelectedValue == "-1")
            {
                $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).prop("disabled", true);
            }
            else
            {
                $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).prop("disabled", false);
                //Get Current Year from Dropdown and Converting to Integer for performing math operations
                var currentSelectedYear = parseInt($(this).val());
               
                //As Index of Javascript Month is from 0 to 11 therefore totalMonths are 11 NOT 12
                var totalMonths = 11;
                if (currentSelectedYear == currentYear) {
                    totalMonths = currentMonth;
                }
                var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
                //Emptying the Month Dropdown to clear our last values
                $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).empty();
                
                $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).append('<option value="-1">-Month-</option>');                                

                //Appending Current Valid Months
                for (var month = 0; month <= totalMonths; month++) {
                    $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).append('<option value="'+ (month+1) +  '">' + monthNames[month] + '</option>');
                }
            }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    
<select id="dropDownYear1">
    <option value="-1">-Year-</option>
</select>
<select id="dropDownYearMonth">
    <option value="-1">-Month-</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, where the Intl object is supported, month names are available from [*Date.prototype.toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString). This can adopt the browser default language or you can set it.

See [*MDN Date.prototype.toLocaleString()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Example:_Checking_for_support_for_locales_and_options_arguments) and the support matrix. I doesn't work in IE 10 or lower, but there's good support in other browsers.

E.g.

```js
function addRemainingMonthOptions(id, lang) {

  // Make sure element exists
  var sel = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!sel) return;

  // Get current date, set day to 1 so not affected by adding months
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(1);
  
  // Add options until end of year
  do {
    month = d.toLocaleString(lang,{localeMatcher: 'best fit', month:'short'})
    sel.appendChild(new Option(month, month));
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() +1);
  } while (d.getMonth() > 0)
}

// Add remaining months in browser default langauge (lang is undefined)
addRemainingMonthOptions('theMonth0')
// … in Russian
addRemainingMonthOptions('theMonth1', 'ru')
// … in Arabic
addRemainingMonthOptions('theMonth2', 'ar')
```

```html
<select id="theMonth0">
</select>
<select id="theMonth1">
</select>
<select id="theMonth2">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fyyear').click(function(){
            var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
            var nextYear = new Date().getFullYear()+1;
            var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth()-3;
            var monthList = "#month";
            var fy = currentYear +'-'+nextYear;
            var currentFYear = $('#fyyear').val();
            var totalMonths = 11;
            if(currentFYear == fy)
            {
                totalMonths = currentMonth;
            }
            var monthNames = ["April","May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December","January", "February", "March"];
            $(monthList).empty();
            for (var month = 0; month <= totalMonths; month++)
            {
                $(monthList).append('<option>' + monthNames[month] + '</option>');
            }
        });
```

Comment: This Javascript function will be used to display the month list till current Month for the current Financial year or All Months for the Previous Financial Years.